# Adding a comma after every input HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs

I've seen quite a few listings related to this question but none of them seem to work or don't exactly fit my requirements.

I have an HTML document with an input `type="text"`.
I am trying to accept numbers from the user and after every input, a comma will appear.

Ex.

```
User Enters 1234 -> Display 1,2,3,4
```

I would like the values to be saved to an array on the back side so same example

```
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2
array[2] = 3
array[3] = 4
```

My HTML FILE Looks like this

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" ng-keyup="format(this)">
</div>
```

The top DIV CLASS utilizes a ng-controller

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-controller="SplitCtrl">
```

I am just curiously how I can call that controller to create a function that will separate my inputs.

Comment: Strings in C# also act as a char array, you can get the length and iterate through it. Else you can use `Substring` to divide the string in smaller strings of one char.

Comment: Are you using AngularJS or Angular (is your code in Javascript or Typescript)? This is easy to do in C#, but that's not going to matter in an AngularJS or Angular application (unless you are going to do this in a call to the server). You need to pick one language

Comment: This is AngularJS. Sorry if that wasn't clear. So my code is Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="SplitCtrl">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-keyup="format($event)">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('SplitCtrl',['$scope' ,function ($scope) {
  $scope.format = function(e) {
    if ($scope.text.length > 1) {
      var text = $scope.text.split('').filter(function(_, i) {
        return (i % 2) === 0;//filter out previous commas
      }).join('') + e.key;
      $scope.text = text.split('').join(',');
    }
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't need numbers with multiple characters (like 10) this should work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.8.0/angular.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<script>
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.change = function() {
        $scope.numbers = $scope.numbers.replace(/,/g, '').split('').join(',');
      };
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="AppController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="numbers" ng-change="change()" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```